# hide and show div content when clicking link inside grid

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to hide or show div content when clicking on link. I have tried to use the same approach used in http://jsfiddle.net/fXE9p/
and still didn't work.

```
<body>
    Click a button to make it visible:<br /><br />
    <a href="#" class="one">One</a>
    <a href="#" class="two">Two</a>
    <a href="#" class="three">Three</a>
    <a href="#" class="four">Four</a><br /><br />

    <div id="one">One</div>
    <div id="two">Two</div>
    <div id="three">Three</div>
    <div id="four">Four</div><br/><br/>
</body>
```

```js
$("div").hide();
// Show chosen div, and hide all others
$("a").click(function (e) {
    //e.preventDefault();
    $("#" + $(this).attr("class")).show().siblings('div').hide();
});
```

What I'm trying to do is place a link in grid block, and once it's clicked the content of div will be displayed (the content including form fields). Is it not working because of the grid?

this is my code
html:

```
<div role="main" class="ui-content">

            <fieldset>
                        <div class="ui-grid-a">
                            <div class="ui-block-a" id="conGridOne"><a href="#" class="linkA">Block A</a></div>
                            <div class="ui-block-b" id="conGridTwo"><a href="#contactTabTwo">block B</a></div>
                        </div>
            </fieldset>
                <div id="linkA">
                    <p>This is block one</p>
                </div>
                <div id="id2" class="tabContent" data-href="contactTabTwo">
                    <h1>this is block two</h1>            
                </div>        


    </div>
```

jquery:

```
$("a.linkA").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#" + $(this).attr("class")).show();
    });
```

CSS:

```
#linkA{

display: none;
```

}

and yes i have linked jquery to my html document as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please include the code you are using, the code provided it's the same as the jsfiddle and is working fine.

Comment: Did you add reference to jquery in your webpage?

Answer (score 0):

simple just assign the div a class that has display: block; and set the div by default to display:none;

**EDIT:** didn't realize that you wanted to hide the other divs when one was clicked.
    
      
      
        div{
          display:none;
        }

```
    </style>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <body>
Click a button to make it visible:<br /><br />
<a href="#" class="one">One</a>

<a href="#" class="two">Two</a>
<a href="#" class="three">Three</a>
<a href="#" class="four">Four</a><br /><br />
<div id="one">One</div>
<div id="two">Two</div>
<div id="three">Three</div>
<div id="four">Four</div><br/><br/>
</body>
<script>
$("a").click(function() {
 $("#"+this.className).siblings("div").hide();
  $("#"+this.className).show();
});
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**
CodePen Link added: 
http://codepen.io/DeveloperKnowledge/pen/KpPgbL

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have your Script tags for jQuery . I prefer to put them just before the `</body>` tag.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

You can find the latest jQuery CDN here:
http://jquery.com/download/